# Nested Loops Question___>

Tags: python, loops, nested

could someone help me out with this question? I'm sure it's simple but I'm new to python.

Question: Create a program where every person meets the other
persons = `[ “John”, “Marissa”, “Pete”, “Dayton” ]`

What I have so far:

```
persons = ["John", "Marissa", "Pete", "Dayton"]

them = ["Dayton", "Pete", "Marissa", "John"]

for x in persons:
    for y in them:
        print(x, "Meets", y)
```

This works but I don't want to print the same person meeting themself.

Comment: Use indices and just 1 copy of the list. `for i in range(n-1):` followed by `for j in range(i+1,n):` is a standard way to iterate over pairs of distinct indices `(i,j)`.

Comment: @JohnColeman That wouldn't work in this case as there are two lists.

Comment: Try `if x != y: print(...)`.

Comment: @Selcuk I think that it is OP who thought up the second list, with the original problem statement only involving a single list of people, though I could of course be wrong.

Comment: Did you make up the lists? or were they given to you randomly?

Comment: Also your code will print both `John Meets Dayton` and `Dayton Meets John`. Is that required behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

This code should work:

```
persons = ["John", "Marissa", "Pete", "Dayton"]

them = ["Dayton", "Pete", "Marissa", "John"]

for x in persons:
    for y in them:
        if not x==y:
            print(x, "Meets", y)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `combinations()` from `itertools` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)). This will have each person meeting everyone else exactly once, so you'd have `John meets Marissa` or `Marissa meets John` but not both.

```
from itertools import combinations

persons = ["John", "Marissa", "Pete", "Dayton"]

for person1, person2 in combinations(persons, 2):
    print(person1, "Meets", person2)
```

Output:

```
John Meets Marissa
John Meets Pete
John Meets Dayton
Marissa Meets Pete
Marissa Meets Dayton
Pete Meets Dayton
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @itsanantk answer, when you want to eliminate same pairs (i.e. treat "John Meets Marissa" and "Marissa Meets John" as a same), you could use following pattern:

```
persons = ["John", "Marissa", "Pete", "Dayton"]
for i, x in enumerate(persons):
    for y in persons[i+1:]:
        print(x, "Meets", y)
```

Here, every person meets every person standing *after it* in the list.

Same effect could be achieved using more concise syntaxes of `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import combinations
persons = ["John", "Marissa", "Pete", "Dayton"]
for x, y in combinations(persons,2):
    print(x, "Meets", y)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should also work:

```
persons = ["John", "Marissa", "Pete", "Dayton"]
them = ["Dayton", "Pete", "Marissa", "John"]

for x in range(len(persons)):
    for y in range(len(them)):
        if x != y:
           print(f'{persons[x]} meets {them[y]}')
```

Output:

John meets Pete

John meets Marissa

Marissa meets Dayton

Marissa meets John

Pete meets Dayton

Pete meets John

Dayton meets Pete

Dayton meets Marissa